# Sort specific group within a data frame with conditions in R

Tags: r

I need help in order to subset my data frame within groups, here is the data frame:

```
Group_name  Event   colomn1 colomn2 colomn3 colomn4
Group1  1   1   1   1   0
Group1  2   2   2   4   2
Group1  3   2   2   4   2
Group2  1   6   6   6   0
Group3  1   2   2   2   0
Group3  2   2   2   2   0
Group4  1   2   2   5   3
Group4  2   2   2   2   0
```

And I want to keep Groups where the colomn4 values = 0 and remove the others:

So I should get:

```
Group_name  Event   colomn1 colomn2 colomn3 colomn4
Group2  1   6   6   6   0
Group3  1   2   2   2   0
Group3  2   2   2   2   0
```

Have you an idea to do it in R?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `dplyr`, you can do:

```
df %>%
 group_by(Group_name) %>%
 filter(all(colomn4 == 0))

  Group_name Event colomn1 colomn2 colomn3 colomn4
  <chr>      <int>   <int>   <int>   <int>   <int>
1 Group2         1       6       6       6       0
2 Group3         1       2       2       2       0
3 Group3         2       2       2       2       0
```

Or the same with `base R`:

```
df[with(df, ave(colomn4, Group_name, FUN = function(x) all(x == 0))) == 1, ]

  Group_name Event colomn1 colomn2 colomn3 colomn4
4     Group2     1       6       6       6       0
5     Group3     1       2       2       2       0
6     Group3     2       2       2       2       0
```

Or:

```
df[as.logical(with(df, ave(colomn4, Group_name, FUN = function(x) all(x == 0)))), ]
```

Or (proposed by @Ronak Shah):

```
df[with(df, ave(colomn4 == 0, Group_name, FUN = all)), ]
```

Comment: @Ronak Shah that was something I tried to achieve, added it to my post. Thank you :)

Comment: Alright thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

With base R you can do:

```
data[ave(data$colomn4, data$Group_name, FUN = sum) == 0,]

  Group_name Event colomn1 colomn2 colomn3 colomn4
4     Group2     1       6       6       6       0
5     Group3     1       2       2       2       0
6     Group3     2       2       2       2       0
```

or with `data.table`

```
DT <- as.data.table(data)
DT[, exclude := all(colomn4 == 0), by = Group_name][(exclude)]
```

Comment: when using [tag:data.table] I would do: `DT[, if( all(colomn4 == 0) ) .SD, by = Group_name]`